# Complex grouping of sales in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a requirement to get or group the sales of particular products starting from the first day of the sales, so that to get a cohort analysis on the sales.I'm using Postgres DB ,so any help with this SQL or idea on how to achieve the expected result will be of great help.

**Input**

```
product    code   order_date  quantity 
Product_1  001    2020-01-02    30
Product_1  001    2020-01-03    31
Product_1  001    2020-02-23    55
Product_1  001    2020-04-30    125
Product_2  002    2020-03-20    110
Product_2  002    2020-04-03    59
```

**Expected Output**

```
product    code  quantity grouped_date   Month
Product_1  001      61      month_0      2020-01  
Product_1  001      55      month_1      2020-02
Product_1  001      0       month_2      2020-03
Product_1  001      125     month_3      2020-04
Product_2  002      110     month_0      2020-03
Product_2  002      59      month_1      2020-04
```

So from the above sample input , i would like to get the first sale date of each product and mark that month as month_0 and next month as month_1 and the next month as month_2 etc and sum up all the sales of those month to get a cohort analysis of products starting from the month of each products sale.

Below is the sample query which i used, but unable to add a grouping as it seems to be complicated for me.Any help will be much appreciated.

```
WITH base as
(
select product,code,order_date::DATE as order_date,quantity 
FROM sales
WHERE order_date::DATE BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE
)
,first_date_of_sales AS
(
SELECT product,code,MIN(order_date) as first_order_date FROM base
    GROUP BY product,code
)
SELECT * FROM first_date_of_sales
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below mentioned query:

```
with cte as (
select product, code,
generate_series(min(date_trunc('month',order_date)), max(date_trunc('month',order_date)), interval '1 month') dt_series
from tab1 group by product, code
),
cte1 as(
select row_number() over (partition by product order by dt_series) sno, 
product, code, dt_series 
from cte
)

select 
cte1.product, 
cte1.code,
coalesce(sum(quantity),0) "quantity",
concat('month_',sno-1) "grouped_date", 
to_char(dt_series,'yyyy-mm') "Month" from cte1 
left join tab1 on cte1.dt_series=date_trunc('month', order_date) and cte1.product=tab1.product
group by cte1.product,cte1.code,dt_series,concat('month_',sno-1),to_char(dt_series,'yyyy-mm')
order by cte1.product,cte1.code,dt_series
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=16a2ad03dadb567da303321c024e2b44)